# Is there anyway to change the default query on MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

On the workbench when you "Select Rows - Limit 300 rows" on the table for a quick query, it autofills and runs:

```
SELECT * FROM [table_name];
```

I want to see if it is possible to make that default to:

```
SELECT * FROM [table_name] ORDER BY id DESC;
```

I rarely care about the oldest data, which the original default runs, but rather the newest data. For now I have been adding the ORDER BY portion manually, but would be nice if it just defaulted to that.

Comment: Wouldn't make much sense as there will be tables without a column `id`.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the quick reply. But would be nice, if it had an id field to default to the other query, but I might be asking too much. Anyways, it's not really a problem, just a inconvenience.

Comment: If you click on a column header it will re-sort the data. If you click on the id column header it will re-sort in descending order, for example.

Comment: @Honeyboy Wilson, But that only sorts what you currently have, so if your limit is set to 300 and you have more than 300 items (My particular table is in the millions), then it just sorts the first 300 that show by default.

Comment: Crazy that there seems to be absolutely no way to change the default query in 2023.